# How to check if new line with character is present in string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

what is way to find if string has new line character(/n) followed by any other character in javascript?
Currently I'm doing this:

```
if (((mystring).slice(-2)) == "/\n/A") {
    //mycode
}
```

I want to check whether last two characters of string are \n and A.
My thing is not working. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check whether last two characters of string are \n and A.

You can use [`String#endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```js
const A = `this is a valid string\nA`;
const B = `this is an invalid string`;

console.log('A', A.endsWith('\nA'));
console.log('B', B.endsWith('\nA'));
```